# Find all descendants of root node using CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to show how many descendants the parent node have but in below query it's showing the other way around.

```
WITH AssemblyList AS 
(
SELECT 
        T.PKAssembly,
        T.FKParentAssembly,
        T.AssemblyNumber, 
        0 AS AssemblyLevel
FROM CT_Assemblies T WHERE T.FKParentAssembly = T.PKAssembly AND T.FKCustomer = 12 AND T.FKState = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT  A.PKAssembly,
        A.FKParentAssembly,
        A.AssemblyNumber,
        AL.AssemblyLevel + 1
FROM CT_Assemblies A 
INNER JOIN AssemblyList AS AL ON A.FKParentAssembly = AL.PKAssembly 
WHERE A.FKParentAssembly != A.PKAssembly AND A.FKCustomer = 12 AND A.FKState = 1
)
SELECT * FROM AssemblyList
```

In my table structure we have PKAssembly as childId and FKParentAssembly as parentId. If both are same for a record it means its the parent or single root. 
The result shows like this precisely:

```
PKAssembly      FKParentAssembly     AssemblyNumber     AssemblyLevel
500             500                  A11111              0
507             506                  A77777              6
```

Here the first record should show 6 and the second one should show 0 but its coming the opposite way.
What should i change in the query to make it work?

Comment: I m confused you said PKAssembly is child and FKParentAssembly is parent, so the first record you showed is 0 should be right and you forced it to be 0 in your query.  BTW: i used connect by to do search like this, not sure if there are similar one in sqlserver.

Comment: Yes that's how CTE works. It traverse from root to leaf while incrementing the counters. The first record is the Parent and I want to see assembly level 6 which means it has 6 child items but its showing the child item to be at 6 level down.

Comment: It usually helps to understand and answer the question if you provide some sample data and what result you expect to see based on that sample data.